# After I installed a new template, some of my cron jobs couldn't be added to schedule table

Tags: cron

After I installed a new template, some of my cron jobs, especially the cron job which added by our own integration module from Magento to Netsuite, could be added to cron schedule, I checked the cron schedule table many times.

And it's wiered that sometimes these tasks could be added to schedule successfully and then executed, it's just not stable.

And recently we did meet memory limit problems for some pages, and also for cron job, after we install this new template. After I add more init memory to cron.php, the memeory limit issue solved, but some cron jobs could be scheduled.

Don't know anyone else have met this kinds of issues
Environment: Magento Community 1.9.2.4

Comment: How can I edit my question? I should said that these cron jobs "can't be added to shedule", I writed "could be added" above. And also, "could not be scheduled" it should be, but I put "could be scheduled", what's a big difference..

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem partly solved by correct some erros existed in the database, and adjust some MySQL variables to get better performance(like, open table cache, key buffer size etc.), I think when MySQL server is crowded and slow, after installed a complicated template, things become even worse, then some of this cron couldn't be scheduled..

Now it's partly recovered, because there are still some cron job couldn't be scheduled, so I will continue work at this direction to tune up MySQL database performance.

Just FYI.